# How do we decide the sign of a an integral in the divergence theorem

Tags: integration, contour-integration, 3d, divergence-operator, electromagnetism

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/144Hf.png)

From the example on the picture above, the surface of the front face of the cube lies on a positive $x$, therefore, $a_x$ is positive.

But why is $a_x$ negative in the case of the back face?

To make it more general, assume we are integrating with a two-dimensional space $(x,y)$, can we assume that the integral is in the negative $z$ dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select the surface element ${\rm d}{\bf S} = {\rm d}S\hat{\bf S}$, in such a way that the unitary vector $\hat{\bf S}$ points *outwards*. So in this case, the front face points along the vector $\hat{\bf x}$, whereas the back face points along the vector $\color{red}{-}\hat{\bf x}$

Comment: ahh I see, thank you, sir. This explains it.